# Understanding monad transformers in Scala

Tags: scala, monads

I'm trying to understand how to use Monad Transformers. I read the [wiki article](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers) about it and still have some questions.

We have `IO` monad that needs to read input from user. But the input is not always provided. So it's `Option`. To simplify we can define a monad `OptionT` which "incapsulates" actions of `IO` monad.

In my particular case I have two monads of types `Future[Option[String]]` and `Future[List[Int]]`. It means to simplify it I need two different transformers `ListT[T]` and `OptionT[T]` for each monad type respectively in which I embed `Future` behavior... Right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right, the way monad transformers work is to help you on working with a "inner" monad that is being "transformed" by a "outer" monad.

So `F[Option[A]` can be turned into a `OptionT[F, A]` (where `F` is any monad), which is much easier to work with.

About `ListT`, it may not be so easy. For instance `cats` doesn't provide one, see [their FAQ](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/docs/src/main/tut/faq.md#listt) for more info. As they suggest, you can use `Nested` as a replacement for the cases in which you don't need a `flatMap`, for example:

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._
import cats.data.Nested
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Implicits.global

val futList = Future(List(1, 2, 3))
Nested(futList).map(_ + 1).value // Future(List(2, 3, 4))
```

If you want another take on monad transformers, here's a short article I authored: https://blog.buildo.io/monad-transformers-for-the-working-programmer-aa7e981190e7

Comment: you're missing a `]` in `F[Option[A]`